# When I click a button my style doesn't work at all

Tags: javascript, arrays

when I click button for example(remove btn or add btn), the selected style doesn't work at all???

I think something went wrong in renderList function but I can't find it.
I checked other lines couldn't find my mistake

```js
const inputEl = document.getElementById("input-item");
const addBtn = document.querySelector(".add-btn");

let lists = [];

const renderList = () => {
  const listContainer = document.querySelector(".list-container");
  listContainer.innerHTML = "";

  lists.forEach((item) => {
    const liContainer = document.createElement("li");
    liContainer.setAttribute("id", item.id);
    liContainer.classList.add("list", item.selected ? "selceted" : "not");

    const listName = document.createElement("p");
    listName.innerText = item.name;
    listName.addEventListener("click", () => markSelected(item.id));

    const iconBtn = document.createElement("img");
    iconBtn.setAttribute("src", "/icons/close-square-svgrepo-com.svg");
    iconBtn.addEventListener("click", () => deletList(item.id));

    liContainer.appendChild(listName);
    liContainer.appendChild(iconBtn);
    listContainer.appendChild(liContainer);
  });
};

const addList = () => {
  const inputVal = inputEl.value;
  let list;

  if (inputVal.trim() !== "") {
    list = {
      id: Date.now(),
      name: inputVal,
      selected: false,
    };
  }

  inputEl.value = "";
  lists.push(list);
  renderList();

  console.log(lists);
};

addBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  addList();
});

const deletList = (id) => {
  lists = lists.filter((list) => list.id !== id);
  renderList();
};

const markSelected = (id) => {
  lists = lists.map((list) => {
    if (list.id === id) {
      list.selected = !list.selected;
    }

    return list;
  });
  updateList(id);
};

const updateList = (id) => {
  const listElement = document.getElementById(id);
  if (listElement) {
    const task = lists.find((item) => item.id === id);
    if (task.selected) {
      listElement.classList.add("selected");
    } else {
      listElement.classList.add("selected");
    }
  }
};

renderList();
```

repo: https://github.com/MahzyarSaadat/todo-list/tree/main

try me to find the solution

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Typo? You seem to be adding a class called `selceted`, but your class name in the css in your github is `selected`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite helpful if you create a sandbox example that people can test/reproduce.

The issue is most likly to do with your css / styles.
When you are adding the 'selected' class with

```
liContainer.classList.add("list", item.selected ? "selceted" : "not");
```

it is actually adding two space separated class's `list selected` or `list not`.
To add a style to a space-separated class, you need to set up `.list.not` and `.list.selected` classes in a style sheet.

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/jacoballen4534/7L5phoxz/29/) is a sandbox to your code with an example css class setup to show that it is actualy working. (Note the `close-square-svgrepo-com` image wont work in the sandbox)

Note that the onclick is only on the `p` tag (only the text, not the entire row). If you want the entire row to be clickable, you will need to change the component you attach the onClick to.

Answer (score -2):

Stop declaring identifiers intended to be VARIABLES, as constants or you won’t be able to modify them.

For example, you’ve got…

```
const listName = document.createElement("p");
    listName.innerText = item.name;
```

A constant means it CAN NEVER AND WILL NEVER CHANGE VALUE during its usage.

Constant declarations are useful for PRE-SET things like the *days of the week*, or *the months of the year*, which never change.

Constants are great for O/S memory management because the O/S knows the identifier will never grow or shrink in memory size (remains fixed), so it is moved to the top of the code segment and the O/S doesn't have to worry about it any more.

So don’t declare an identifier as a constant if you plan to set its value after the declaration.

Btw, look in your debug console... you should see tons of errors informing that you can’t change a constant.

Comment: i change the constant to let but the codes still have bug

Comment: Well now you’ll have a new set of messages in the error console… what do they say?

Comment: @PassThru, that is not quite true. While you are correct about not being able to re-assign `listName` when it is declared as a `const`, you can however, re-assign sub-components of `listName` (e.g. `listName.innerText = item.name` is perfectly legal and will have no errors).

Comment: I checked all constants. There are no reassignments at all. Also, `const` and `let` have a miniscule impact on performance. It is premature to optimize for that. Instead, use what makes sense. A `const` communicates that I do not intend this variable to point to any other object than the initial one. The original question does this correctly.